# Merge 5 NSStrings in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, merge, nsstring

I have multiple `NSStrings` and i wish to merge them into one other, here is my code so far...

```
NSString *newURL = [_parameters objectForKey:@"url"];
NSString *emailBody = @"Hey!<br>I just snipped my long url with <a href=\"...\">My Cool App for iPhone</a> in just a few seconds!<p><b><a href=\""+newURL+@"\">"+newURL+@"</a></b></p>";
```

Comment: lol :) mwahaha, i need help with this - how the hell is it spam?

Comment: I think the question was OK whilst the "hint" to search in iTunes was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
NSString *emailBody = [ NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hey!<br>I just snipped my long url with <a href=\"http://itunes.com/app/SnippetySnip\">Snippety Snip for iPhone</a> in just a few seconds, why not check it out?<p><b><a href=\"%@\">%@</a></b></p>", newURL ];
```

Answer (score 13):

If you know the number of your existing strings, you can just concat them:

```
NSString* longString = [firstString stringByAppendingString:secondString];
```

or:

```
NSString* longString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A string: %@, a float: %1.2f", @"string", 31415.9265];
```

If you have an arbitrary number of strings, you could put them in an NSArray and join them with:

```
NSArray* chunks  = ... get an array, say by splitting it;
NSString* string = [chunks componentsJoinedByString: @" :-) "];
```

(Taken from http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSString)

Another good resource for string handling in Cocoa is: ["String Programming Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've got multiple strings I recommend using an Array:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"URL", @"person", "body"];
NSString *combined = [array componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

[Formatting string](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html) has better readability and less error-prone:

```
NSString *newURL = [_parameters objectForKey:@"url"];
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hey!<br>I just snipped my long url with <a href=\"http://itunes.com/app/SnippetySnip\">Snippety Snip for iPhone</a> in just a few seconds, why not check it out?<p><b><a href=\"%@\">%@</a></b></p>", newUrl, newUrl];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings in Cocoa using:

[NSString stringByAppendingString:]

Or you could use the [NSString stringWithFormat] method which will allow you to specify a C-style format string with a variable argument list to populate the escape sequences.